# Duplicate Output Destination Error in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using the following query. But when i run it, it gives error

> "Duplicate Output Destination 'ShipmentID'.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO TmpContainersForPLReport " & _
                  "SELECT * FROM Containers INNER JOIN Shipments ON (Containers.ShipmentID = Shipments.ShipmentID)  WHERE Containers.PackinglistentryDate = #" & TxtEntryDate & "# and Containers.PONumber = '" & TxtPONumber & "'" & _
                  " OR Containers.PackinglistentryDate = #" & TxtEntryDate & "# and Containers.SalesOrderNumber = '" & txtSalesOrderNumber & "'"
```

Comment: When you do `Select *` on an `Inner Join` all of the columns will be returned in the dataset from both tables. Therefore, you have 2 `ShipmentID` columns from different tables, but with the same name. Specify what columns you want to be inserted.

Comment: i tried giving only those column names to be inserted, but it said 'Too few parameters.Expected 1'

Comment: Drop the temp table and recreate it. I believe it created the temp table with all of the columns from both tables. Now it's saying you don't have enough fields to fill the table.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting thin error because you are using 'SELECT *' from a JOIN between two tables and the field ShipmentID exists in both tables so you are selecting that field twice.

If you go to this link, you will see that's the description for this error:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209781(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1):

From the join, one can see *ShipmentID* resides in two tables, *Containers* and *Shipments*, and hence the error. For this reason among others, always explicitly reference columns and not abbreviate with `*`. Even so explicitly reference the destination columns in `INSERT` clause.

And as another best practice, consider parameterization over string concatenation. You can so with [DAO querydef parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) with `PARAMETERS` clause. See below example. Do replace the *Cols*.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim qdef As QueryDef

strSQL = "PARAMETERS TxtEntryDateParam Date, TxtPONumberParam Text(255), TxtSalesOrderNumberParam Text(255);" & _
         "INSERT INTO TmpContainersForPLReport (Col1, Col2, Col3) " & _
         "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Containers c " & _
         "INNER JOIN Shipments s ON (c.ShipmentID = s.ShipmentID) " & _
         "WHERE c.PackinglistentryDate = [TxtEntryDateParam] AND c.PONumber = [TxtPONumberParam]" & _
         "   OR c.PackinglistentryDate = [TxtEntryDateParam] AND c.SalesOrderNumber = [TxtSalesOrderNumberParam];"

Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

qdef!TxtEntryDateParam = TxtEntryDate
qdef!TxtPONumberParam = TxtPONumber
qdef!TxtSalesOrderNumberParam = txtSalesOrderNumber

qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```

In fact, you can even save above SQL as a saved Access query which the Jet/ACE Engine caches for best optimized, execution path (i.e., more efficient than VBA string query):

```
Dim strSQL As String

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myAppendQuery")

qdef!TxtEntryDateParam = TxtEntryDate
qdef!TxtPONumberParam = TxtPONumber
qdef!txtSalesOrderNumberParam = txtSalesOrderNumber

qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```